# not different from

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, negation

> If two things are quite similar, you can say that one thing is *not
> **very/much** different* from the other.
>
> If two things are alike, you can say that one thing is *no different* from the other.
> Don't say that one thing is *‘not
> different’* from another.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/different

What grammar issue the author trying to convey here?

Comment: Just that _no different from_ is idiomatic and _not different from_  is not.

Comment: @KateBunting I would not say that it is unidiomatic to say “not different” **generally**, at least it is not in the U.S. In the context of using the phrase “no different,” preferring “no different” over “not different” is a matter of preferring a non-ambiguous phrase over an ambiguous one. Would you really say “The supreme legislative body in the U.K is no different from the British Parliament,” or would you say “not different.”

Comment: Of course you can "say" not different: This car is not different from that car.  This car is no different than that car.  Same thing. The semantic difference between them is zero.

Comment: If you run [an NGram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) for the search string **is no different * that** (actual link being too long to fit into a comment here), you'll see that *This is no different **from** that* is by far the most common preposition (but ***than*** and ***to*** also occur relatively often). Note that *This is [no] different **in** that...* is a completely different construction (which will be followed by a clause explicitly identifying ***why*** something is [not] different to something else).

Comment: The Times Literary Supplement, British economist: True, some of the historical analogies are tendentious: he likes to repeat the argument he first put forward in Sapiens that **theological fictions are not different from the fictions** involved in the creation of corporations https://www.google.com/search?q=paul+seabright&oq=paul+seabright&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l2j46j0i22i30l5.2998j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 And it would mean the same thing with: are no different than

Answer (score 0):

This is not grammar, but about received British usage.

The topic is negating the word “different” to indicate similarity.

> A is not too different from B.

That sentence clearly indicates that A and B are different. We are discussing the degree of difference between two distinguishable things.

> A is not different from B

is ambiguous. It may mean that A is B; that two different names refer to the same thing. Or it may mean that two distinct things are similar in all relevant respects. The source is saying to avoid a locution that has an ambiguous meaning. Notice that this comes up in the context of the phrase “no different,” which is an idiom that unambiguously means that what are being compared are distinct but similar in all relevant respects.

> Jack is no different than any other child his age

does not mean that every child has the same eye color, the same hair color, the same sex, etc. It implies some attribute that is shared by all children of that age.

Comment: I'm scratching my head about your mentioning received British usage.

Comment: @Lambie Did you look at the source? It explicitly states “usage,” and its one reference to U.S. usage comes after British usage.

Comment: Yes, it says (among other things) that the British use "different to" and Americans use "different from" and I don't buy it. Sorry.

Comment: What don’t you buy?

Comment: What I is just said. That the British use different to where the Americans use different from.

Comment: If you compare NGrams for **is no different * that** against AmE and BrE corpuses, it seems pretty clear that although ***from*** is by far the most common preposition both sides of the pond, there's a bit of contention for "second place". In AmE, ***than*** is easily the second most common, but in BrE that slot goes to ***to***.

Comment: I at least am confused. The OP’s question and my answer dealt with the apparently unqualified advice in the OP’s source to avoid “not different.” Nothing in the OP’s question or my answer refers to what preposition is “correct” after “different.”

Comment: [**TOO** (used with a negative word or phrase) "extremely;
very":
_The boss was **none/not** too pleased with the results._](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/too)